# How to pass variable data between two procedures

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables

I am trying to pass variable information from one procedure to another, I'm not very experienced at .net and I was unable to find more information on doing just this.

```
    Sub ValidationScript()
    Dim checkVar As Boolean
    'First consistency check \\ Length based check
    If emailP.InnerText.Length > 3 Then
        If passwordP.InnerText.Length > 5 Then
            checkVar = True
        Else
            Con1.InnerText = "You have entered an Incorrect Email or password."
            checkVar = False
        End If
    Else
        Con1.InnerText = "You have entered an Incorrect Email or password."
        checkVar = False
    End If
End Sub


Sub loginBtn1_Click(checkVar As Boolean) Handles loginBtn1.ServerClick
 if checkVar = true then
     Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")
end sub
```

I am trying to get the information from checkVar to be accessible by the second sub loginBtn1.

Comment: When do you run the Validation sub? It is possible to call this sub when inside the loginBtn1_Click code?

Comment: Declare checkvar  outside of sub. Pass it byRef parameter to your sub, update it within sub. Now second sub should have new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how the ValidationScript is called in your code, but as it is now I think you need to simply change your `Sub ValidationScript` to a `Function ValidationScript` that returns a Boolean

```
Function ValidationScript() As Boolean

    Dim checkVar As Boolean = False

    'First consistency check \\ Length based check
    If emailP.InnerText.Length > 3 Then
        If passwordP.InnerText.Length > 5 Then
            checkVar = True
        Else
            Con1.InnerText = "You have entered an Incorrect Email or password."
        End If
    Else
        Con1.InnerText = "You have entered an Incorrect Email or password."
    End If
    return checkVar
End Function
```

and then call it inside the Click event (but use it with the correct parameters)

```
Sub loginBtn1_Click(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e As EventArgs ) Handles loginBtn1.ServerClick
    if ValidationScript() = true then
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")
    else
        .....
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a bit too early, if your are in your first stages of learning NET languages and the ASP.NET world, but to avoid to reinvent the wheel remember to read [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h(v=vs.100).aspx)